# Dropdown issues with Twitter Bootstrap when used in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I was playing with MVC3 Asp.Net and trying to implement the Twitter Bootstrap into the project. I got the basic thing working but not the dropdown. I have the following html code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
 <body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
       <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Test Project</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Main Menu with SubMenu<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>First Menu</li>
                <li>Second Menu</li>
                <li>Third Menu</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        alert("Starting Dropdown");
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
</script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </body>
 </html>
```

For some reason the dropdown is not showing up, I have tried couple of things but it's not working. I am not sure if its related to the versions I use. They are

ASP.NET MVC3

jQuery 1.5.1
Bootstrap CSS - v2.1.1
Bootstrap Download JS - v2.1.1

I would appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap uses the jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function for delegating events, which was introduced in version 1.7.  You need to upgrade to at least that version for the jQuery plugins, like **bootstrap-collapse.js**, to function.

Comment: Thank You @Merv. Downloaded the latest jQuery and fixed it up. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are ommiting the dropdown for collapsed state:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</a>
```

And you are forcing that collapsed state with class `collapse`, delete it:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
```

Comment: Thank You for your response. I have updated the html code, it still does now show up the dropdown.